# Animation not working for UIView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

In my app i have two tab bars. Lets say A & B. A tab has a table view in which i'm animating a UIView at one particular cell. It's a continuous animation(UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat). It's working fine till now. If i go to tab B and come back to tab A. Animation is not working. And also it's not working when the cell hides while scrolling. I'm not sure where i'm wrong. Suggestion would be more appreciated and let me know if more details need.

CellforRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.label.addSubview(self.MethodA(cell.label.bounds))

fun MethodA(bounds: CGRect) -> UIView {
var xxx = AnimationView(frame: CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y, startingPoint, bounds.size.height))

        UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, delay: 0, options:
            UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: { () -> Void in
                let totalWidth: CGFloat = 100
                let animationWidth: CGFloat = totalWidth - startingPoint
                var frame : CGRect = xxx.frame
                frame.size.width = (animationWidth + startingPoint)
                xxx.frame = frame

            },completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Code would be helpful

Comment: A label seems a very unlikely thing to want to add a subview to...